# How to replace word in Python. But "i" to "oraz" and "oraz" to "i"

Tags: python, string, replace

I have problem, I replace before replaced word and I don't know how to recognize that word was replaced already. Please someone can help me?

```
from typing import Tuple, Dict, Any, List

wordToReplace: Tuple[str, str, str, str] = ("i", "oraz", "nigdy", "dlaczego")
dictWord: Dict[str, str] = dict(i="oraz", oraz="i", nigdy="prawie nigdy", dlaczego="czemu")

temporaryText = []
tmpLine: List[str] = []

file = input("Give me file: ")

with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        for word in wordToReplace:
            tmpLine = line.replace(("{} ".format(word)), dictWord[word])
            tmpLine = tmpLine.replace((" {} ".format(word)), dictWord[word])
            tmpLine = tmpLine.replace(" {}".format(word), dictWord[word])
        temporaryText.append(tmpLine)
```

Comment: See [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and use `rf'\b{word}\b'` as the pattern.  `\b` is a word break match.

Comment: re.sub is returning me that word for what i want to replace, i don't get it